# How to prevent MVC 4 Web API from returning HTML for 400 Bad Request

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I've set up a brand new, blank ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Api project using the default project template (Visual Studio 2010, .NET 4.0) . When I browse to `http://localhost:5234/Api/Values/a..a`, I get the following HTML result:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bad Request</title>
        ...
```

***How can I override this behavior so that I can return a custom XML or JSON error result?***

Comment: Is your URL correct? Do you really have this /a..a/?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio I'm intentionally creating a bad request here. I'd like a custom error message on a bad request.

Comment: Best way to avoid `400 Bad Request` is doing `Good Request`!

Comment: @Sergio can you guarantee that my API clients will always do a `Good Request` :)

Comment: @ZaidMasud that's a way to go. Your clients need to know if their request was bad with respons AND http header

Comment: @Sergio exactly, how do I create such a response? That's exactly my question :)

Comment: When browsing to the URL, the Content-Type and Accept headers of the request will allow `text/html`. From an API point of view, it will be `application/json` and the error will not be HTML.

Comment: @MartinHN sorry I still get HTML when I set the headers to application/json

Comment: When I try this, I get 404, not 400. In any case, I think IIS is returning this error before it gets to Web API.

Comment: @MikeWasson I am using VS 2010 .NET 4. I get your behavior on VS 2012 .NET 4.5

Answer (score -1):

Try to set this in your Web.Config

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Tried it, nice guess but make unfortunately doesn't make any difference.